# Self Contained Binary Search with only a single int and array parameter

Tags: c#, arrays

So I have this function I need to create which in addition to a binary search must do some data mining (so not a pure binary search)/

CustomBinarySearch(int goal, int[] myArray)

I know quite clearly how to go about making a binary search. The problem stems from the signature of the function. I would normally pass the index values of the sub-array as I recursively call it but I am required to maintain the original signature.

Is there any way to pass a sub-segment of an array without creating a new array? I am trying to be efficient with my code.

aka something like CustomBinarySearch(goal, myArray[startIndex, endIndex])?

Comment: You may want to read up on [ArraySegment<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

> The problem stems from the signature of the function. I would normally pass the index values of the sub-array as I recursively call it but I am required to maintain the original signature.

Make your public method call a private method that has the signature you prefer.

> Is there any way to pass a sub-segment of an array without creating a new array?

This feature is proposed for C# 7.

Comment: I have thought about the private method but I am not sure if I would be allowed to do that hence the post. I will look into it.